# AutoResizing a button based on title text content

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uibutton, autoresize

So I have a strange issue which could be a bug or me being stupid.

I have a button in a cell. The cell shows the logged in users facebook friends. If they are already a user of the app it shows the button as Play, else it shows Invite Me...

```
UIButton *playButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"fbCell_Invite_30h"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 5, 15, 5)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Invite me";
if ([self.fbFriendsUsingApp containsObject:[friend valueForKey:@"id"]]) {
    playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Play";
}
```

This all works fine and not an issue. However, when the button text is invite me it shows as this:
[image]

In storyboard interface builder the button is setup like this:
[image]

What is strange is that if I click the middle arrow <------> to make the width stretch, the title text stops working and they all show 'Play' ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the text of the button using

`[playButton setTitle:@"Invite Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

instead of

`playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Invite Me;`

I've found that if I don't use the first approach above the changes to the button text don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the size of the `NSString` that you are setting as the button label and then resize the button accordingly:

```
CGSize labelSize = [labelString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]]; 
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
```

You will probably want to add a little to the CGSize as padding, but play with it and find the result you desire.